# Kubernetes Mounting Hostpath to specific location within container

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

---

I'm trying to translate a bunch of docker-compose files into kubernetes yamls.  I have used [kompose](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose), which has gotten me part way, but I'm getting stuck on one particular part for multiple containers.

This is one of the containers. Notice the docker container is mounting `/u/data/. . .` to `/var/lib/mysql`.  This is actually necessary as the mysql directory contains the database and configurations.

```
server1-backend-mysql:
image: mysql
container_name: server-backend-mysql
restart: always
volumes:
   - /u/data/server-backend-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
networks:
  - eolnet
```

What is the correct way to make this happen in Kubernetes? Note that for k8 I will be mounting an nfs volume (this is only for testing purposes).

I did look into [hostpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/), but so far no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When declaring a Pod, specify the volume at `spec.volumes`, and then the volume mount at `spec.containers[*].volumeMounts`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: server1-backend-mysql
spec:
  containers:
  - image: mysql
    name: mysql
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      name: mysql-data
  volumes:
  - name: mysql-data
    hostPath:
      path: /u/data/...
      type: Directory
```

When declaring a `Deployment` or `StatefulSet` (which you *should* do instead of declaring a Pod), move the respective configurations to `spec.template.spec.volumes` and `spec.template.spec.containers[*].volumeMounts`.
For more information, have a look at the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath).

---

As a side note unrelated to your question: if you're planning to run MySQL from a NFS volume, keep in mind that running MySQL from NFS is possible, but [not something that MySQL is really optimized for](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/disk-issues.html). Be sure to configure your MySQL server accordingly, and check if your environment permits you to use a networked block device (and not a network file system) like a Ceph RBD volume or similar.

Comment: No, this is not how we intend to run this. I am just putting together a quick proof of concept! Thank for the tip though, let me try this and see.